# A rule for identifying the stressed syllable in abstract nouns ending in -ity. Is it foolproof?

Tags: pronunciation, suffixes, stress

When I was a student I was taught that the stressed syllable in an **abstract noun** **ending in -ity** is always the antepenultimate.

e.g.

relia**bi**lity

sponta**ne**ity

a**bi**lity

fe**li**city

e**ter**nity

**ra**rity

etc.   Is this rule foolproof?  Can anyone think of an exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *Pity*

Unless you accept the loss of an *i*, the best such word is *pity*.
That’s because in that case Latin *pietās, pietātem* was whittled
away till it had no antepenult left to it, and so you have no chance
to stress something that isn’t there. :) The version that didn’t get
quite so pared down became *piety*, which is stressed
antepenultimately like most of the rest of them.

Even very short words of this pattern have the stress on the antepenult, like *acuity, amity, deity, fatuity, laity, paucity, unity*. The most common of these words end in *‑acity, ‑ality, ‑anity, ‑arity,
‑ariety, ‑bility, ‑eity, ‑idity, ‑ility, ‑inity, ‑iety, ‑ivity,
‑ocity, ‑osity, ‑uity*. Some are even productive as Modern English suffixes in their own
right, like *‑bility*. And all are stressed antepenultimately.

These words all come originally from Latin *‑tās, ‑tātem* for a
state or condition. All the rest either retained enough syllables
to retain an earlier stress, or else had the intervening *i* lost
altogether, as in *safety* and *plenty*. (But compare *royalty*).

A few such words had the Latin suffix joined to a consonant stem
as in *faculty, honesty, puberty*, but here again you have no *i*
before the *‑ty* — and you still have antepenultimate stress.

To have another syllable stressed than the antepenult, it would
need either a “long” *i* sound (actually a diphthong) in the penult like *whitey* or *almighty*, or be
stressed at the end, something which doesn’t really fit the English
stress pattern but can be found in the common pronunciations of
loanwords like *actualité* and *vérité* from French.

There is, I suppose, still the possibility of preäntepenultimate
stress. The closest match there is *difficulty* /ˈdɪfɪkəltɪ/ from
Latin *difficultās, ‑tātem*, which may have gone through a French
*difficulté* en route.

The same process that yielded *pity* also produced *city* from Latin  *cīvitās, ‑tātem* via French *cité*, but that is no longer an abstract noun.

## *Succity*

The OED has one other candidate that meets your criteria, but it is obsolete now and was never more than rare (and was, perhaps, catachrestic): *succity*, about which they say this:

> † sucˈcity. *Obs.* *rare*<sup>-1</sup>.
>
> Etymology: f. L. *succus* juice, sap + *-ity*. But ? an error for *succosity*.
>
> Moisture.
>
> - 1646 Sir T. Browne *Pseud. Ep.* ɪɪ. i. 42 ― A lapidifical succity, and principle which determins prepared materials unto specificall concretions.

How they inferred that the stress was on the penult, I do not know.

So yes, it’s a pretty foolproof rule.

Comment: _Pity_ and _city_ are kind of cheating, since they don't synchronically end in the suffix _-ity_.