# Is it correct to say "the last word but three"?

Tags: expressions

How can I refer to the bold word in the following text?

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea usu erant laboramus, ut vocent
>   consequuntur nec. Usu partem gloriatur ut, eam te quas legendos, est
>   **accumsan** accusamus argumentum te.

Is it correct to say "the last word but three"? I am looking for a general and commonly-used-by-people term.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea usu erant laboramus, ut vocent
>   consequuntur nec. Usu partem gloriatur ut, eam te quas legendos, est
>   accumsan **accusamus** argumentum te.

Comment: Sure. If you can say "the last but one" to mean the penultimate word—which you can—I suppose the rest is just arithmetic.

Comment: I'd call it the "fourth to the last word", or "the fourth word from the end"

Comment: The *pre-antepenultimate word*?

Comment: @bib: I am not sure why you have a hyphen in [*preantepenultimate*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preantepenultimate)

Comment: @Henry Who new. I thought I was neologizing. Now I have to answer. How do I share credit with you?

Comment: @bib I do not need credit.

Comment: @Henry Need, deserve, mere semantics. I am indebted.

Answer (score 4):

The term is *[preantepenultimate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/preantepenultimate)*

> That precedes or stands immediately before the antepenult; the last but three.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Lest there be any confusion about what the above definition means, *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preantepenultimate)* defines it as

> Three before the end; fourth to last.

(Thanks to @Henry who informed me that I was not just making this up.)

Comment: You’re channelling me: [I just mentioned *preäntepenultimate* yesterday](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/278098) when describing the stress in  *difficulty*, which is stressed preäntepenultimately.

Comment: @tchrist, interestingly, there is no last but five or six. There's (pro/supra)preantepenultimate (not found in the OED2, from my recollection) to mean "last but four; fifth from the last"; I've seen a suggestion of forepropreantepenultimate for "last but five; sixth from the last". I suppose supraforepropreantepenultimate, meaning "last but six; seventh from the last", could a coinage for it. I wonder if there are enough unique prefixes to get to "last but ten; eleventh from the last".

Comment: Is the usage of "preantepenultimate" common and understandable to all people?

Comment: It might be familiar to some language geeks, would be understood by most such geeks. Others (regular human beings), not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, it is correct.

Semantically, it is needlessly confusing. Unlike "last but one", it is not at all common.  It should be avoided for that reason.

Comment: What should be used instead?

Comment: I'd say "fourth from the last", which is close to what  @kristinalopez suggested